# Load more in bootsrapselectpicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to loadmore option on mouse scroll using bootsrap selectpicker, how can i do that?

```
 $('#rel_id_contact1').bind('scroll', function(){   
        alert("first");
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() +1 >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        alert("asdasd"); return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What options do you have, where are they defined and what options would you like to have in addition?

Comment: I want to just show alert when scroll reached to bottom..